# subscriptions feed (youtube.search().list)

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

How do I query **my** "subscriptions feed"?

i.e how do I search and list my subscriptions feed (https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions), in an analogue way one searches anything else in youtube via the youtube data api (v3), in python?

```
request = youtube.search().list(
    part="snippet",
    maxResults=25,
    q="surfing"
    )
response = request.execute()
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible with YouTube Data API - maybe with Selenium, you log in and then scrap your own data...

Comment: Check also if you can download this data with Google Takeout and then read those results - see this [explanation](https://jovian.ai/lucafrance/learning-from-my-youtube-watch-history).